# Matrix Issues After Upgrading from 2.4 to 2.6

Tags: matrix, updating

Running into some issues with matrix fields after upgrading from 2.4 to 2.6.

The matrix in the site includes a whole bunch of block types that are used to build row-based pages (e.g., Intro, Profile, News, Text, etc.).

When creating a new page everything works just fine at first. However, when you insert certain block types into the matrix, suddenly you can no longer reorder/collapse/add blocks in that matrix.

I notice that when it breaks, the following error pops up in the console:

```
Uncaught: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined - velocity.min.js
```

Anyone run into this or have ideas to what this might be? I can't seem to find a commonality between the blocks that cause the error and am not sure where to go with this.

Note: this particular matrix config has a *ton* of fields (we've had to extend the php memory limit etc. when saving changes to the config).

Tks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft 2.5 changed from Redactor I to Redactor II, so chances are you just need to update your Redactor configs to the new format: https://craftcms.com/support/redactor-ii-configs

Comment: It was related to Redactor config, but not just the bits mentioned in that support post. They also changed how they handle the 'formattingAdd' property. Might be worth adding a note to that support post that mentions it's not comprehensive and folks may need to look to the Imperavi docs for additional changes to config code? In any case thanks for point me in the right direction!